# C# SQL - Duplicated entries, transfer time and data control

Tags: c#, time, linq-to-sql, duplicates

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but couldn't find an answer that helped me.

I'm reading an .xls file and them adding the rows from it to a database using Linq to SQL. The .xls file as about 500 rows(could have 2\3 times that, easily).

My problem is that I don't want to have duplicates and I'm getting the "unique key" exception when I add multiple rows with one `submitChanges()`.

I can solve this by doing a `submitChanges()` after each row I read from the `.xls` file and use the `SqlException` to catch and solve\jump the problem or check every row if the value already exists in the datatable but I think it will be very time consuming when the data grows to significant size.

I did some tests (starting with a clean DB) and:

- sending everything with a single submitChanges() took around (no verification and empty DB) -  795ms
- sending each row after I read it took (no verification and empty DB) - 1625ms
- sending everything with a single submitChanges() after checking and removing the duplicates took - 1920ms
- sending each row after I read and using a try\catch (`SqlException`) to jump to the next row - 2272ms
- sending each row after I read, check and remove the duplicates took - 2500ms

My main question is, when I have a database with over 10000+ rows (and growing) what is the most efficient way to check\solve the duplicates problem?

Is there another way to do this fast, and with the amount of data increasing through time still be relatively fast?

Thank you in advance.

Edit1:
Thank you for answering.
I add the code for the option of sending everything with one submitChanges() after removing the duplicates from the list. All the other options are with this functions but tweaked.

-Find if value exists on DB

```
private bool checkIfValueExists(int iCheck, adLinqSqlDataContext ctx)
    {
        int checkN = 0;
        checkN = (int) (from Processo in ctx.Processos where Processo.iNumProcesso == iCheck select Processo.idProcesso).FirstOrDefault();
        if (checkN == 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

-Return list without duplicates

```
private List<Processo> removeFromListRepeats(List<Processo> processosComp, adLinqSqlDataContext ctx)
    {
        List<Processo> newProcesso = new List<Processo>();

        foreach (var item in processosComp)
        {
            if (checkIfValueExists(item.iNumProcesso, ctx);)
            {
                newProcesso.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return newProcesso ;
    }
```

-Sendo to DB

```
private void send2DB(List<Processo> processos)
    {
        using (adLinqSqlDataContext adtContext = new adLinqSqlDataContext())
        {            
            processos = removeFromListRepeats(processos, adtContext);

            foreach (var item in processos)
            {
                adtContext.Processos.InsertOnSubmit(item);
            }

            adtContext.SubmitChanges();}
```

Edit2: Did another test with the option suggested by @stuartd compared to all the option I used. It is faster than the others, I'm going to use the option suggested by him.

1 - Convert .xls to List Object / get Id's to List Id's from DB / check if values in List Object exist in List Id's / remove from List Object if exist in List Id's / submit ListObject to DB (one time only)

```
Add values (empty DB)           - 1123ms
Add new values (not empty DB)   - 747ms
```

2 - Convert .xls to List Object / check if values exist in DB (single query for each object in List Object)/ remove from List Object if exists in DB / send List Object grouped (one time only)

```
Add values (empty DB)           - 2471ms
Add new values (not empty DB)   - 2294ms
```

3 - Convert .xls to List Object / check if values exist in DB (single query for each object in List Object)/ if object does not exist in DB submit object, one submit for each new object

```
Add values (empty DB)           - 3143ms
Add new values (not empty DB)   - 2509ms
```

4 - Convert .xls to List Object / submit each Object separately with no verification / when a duplicate is submited a SqlException will be catched and we send the next object.

```
Add values (empty DB)           - 3568ms
Add new values (not empty DB)   - 1723ms
```

Thank you, and if anyone finds a better way to do this please comment...

Comment: Please update your question with the code you're using to update the database. Are you using Entity Framework or Dapper or another object relational mapper? In the past, I've found that the best way to import large spreadsheets is to use the SQL Server Import tool.

Comment: Where are the duplicates coming from? Are the IDs duplicated in the file, or are they duplicating ones that already exist in the database?

Comment: @RobLang edited the question. I believe I'm not using any mapper, Just Linq2Sql, don't know if it's considered a mapper.´

Comment: @stuartd The duplicates come from the .xls files. If it allready exists in the DB the info on the .xls cannot be added to the DB. It will fail to update.

Comment: How about getting all the IDs from the database before uploading, preprocessing the Excel rows to remove duplicates, then upload them in one go?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your existing code is that your `checkIfValueExists` method is looking up the database to see if the records are there, but the records have not been added to the database at that stage.

You could change your `removeFromListRepeats` method to use a dictionary and only add to the dictionary if the key does not already exist, ie something like

```
private List<Processo> removeFromListRepeats(List<Processo> processosComp)
{
    Dictionary<int, Processo>  dict = new Dictionary<int, Processo>();
    foreach (var item in processosComp)
    {
        Processo existingRecord ;
        if (!dict.TryGetValue(item.iNumProcesso , out existingRecord)) 
            dict.Add(item.iNumProcesso , item);         
    }

    return dict.Values.ToList();
}
```